# AngularJS hyphenate string

Tags: angularjs

How could I hyphenate a string in AngularJS.  I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<a href="/houses/{{object.name | lowercase | hyphenate}}/">
```

So that `This Is The String` becomes `this-is-the-string`.

Is there a filter to hyphenate strings similar to `lowercase`?  If not any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a regex to detect and then replace the spaces with hypens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{{'This Is The String'.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')}}`

In your case:

`<a href="/houses/{{object.name.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')}}/">`

Comment: @greorgy, thanks I didn't realise I could use javascript functions like that in AngularJS, makes sense & works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own filters in Angular:

```
app.filter('hyphenate', function() {

  return function(input) {
    output = input.split(' ').join('-');
    return output;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following fiddle on how to write the filter you asked for : 
https://jsfiddle.net/1x2p5v6g/4/

Filter :

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(x) {
        if(x == undefined)
        return "";
        return x.replace(/\s/g , '-');
    };
});
```

Usage :

```
{{ variable| myFilter}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a function or directive

```
function slugify() {
    return function (input) {
        if (!input)
            return;

        // make lower case and trim
        var slug = input.toLowerCase().trim();

        // replace invalid chars with spaces
        slug = slug.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s-]/g, ' ');

        // replace multiple spaces or hyphens with a single hyphen
        slug = slug.replace(/[\s-]+/g, '-');

        return slug;
    };
}
```

Now in html

```
<a href="/houses/{{slugify(object.name)}}/">....</a>
```

This will remove all the invalid characters which are not allowed in URL.